# How to generate a url that redirects to a specific view of another application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a website, where I want to show all my django project.
So, I have a main app, where i'm generating template for all my projects

my home template when we access to the website:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&family=Roboto&display=swap&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <h1></h1>

            <span class="separator"></span>

            <h2></h2>

            <img src="{% static '/home/pictures/logo.png' %}" alt="logo" title="Ceci est mon logo" id="logo">
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" title="Aller à l'accueil">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="contener">
            <section>
                <h3>Projets</h3>

<!--                conteneur                -->
                <div id="projects">

                    {% for projet in projets %}

                        <div class="project">
                            <a href="{% url 'projet-detail' projet.nom_lien %}">
                                <div class="picture">

                                    <img src="{% static '' %}{{ projet.lien_image_presentation }}" alt="Présentation {{ projet.nom }}">
                                </div>
                                <span>{{ projet.nom }}</span>
                                <span class="date-project">{{ projet.date }}</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

            </section>

            <section>
                <h3>Contact</h3>

                <div id="contact">
                    <p>Si vous désirez me contacter, n'hésitez pas à m'écrire à l'adresse <a href="mailto:aymerick.cotche@hotmail.fr"><b>aymerick.cotche@hotmail.fr</b></a></p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <span>2020 © - Aymerick Cotche</span>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

template to see my project description :

```
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{{ projet.nom }} | {{ projet.auteur }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nerko+One&family=Roboto&display=swap&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <h1></h1>

            <span class="separator"></span>

            <h2>{{ projet.nom }}</h2>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" title="Aller à l'accueil">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projets">Projets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="contener">
            <section>
                <h3>Introduction</h3>

                <p> {{ projet.description }} </p>

            </section>

            <section id="production_project">
                <h3>Production</h3>

                <img src="{% static '' %}{{ projet.lien_image_production }}" alt="mon premier projet">
                <a href="{% url 'acceder-projet' projet.nom_lien %}">voir le projet</a>
            </section>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

my urls file for this app:

```
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home),
path('<str:nom_lien>/', views.projet_detail, name='projet-detail'),
]
```

My views file for this app :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from home.models import Projet

def home(request):
    projets = Projet.objects.all().order_by('numero')
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'projets': projets})


def projet_detail(request, nom_lien):
    projet = Projet.objects.get(nom_lien=nom_lien)
    context = {
        'projet': projet
    }
    return render(request, 'home/projets_base.html', context)
```

That I want to do it's to have a link in my project description template, to go to the project, and use the project. The project it's another django app in the same project. and this link should be like "/nom-lien/voirprojet/"

For example in my app "pizza mama" I have this url and views file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('pizzamama/voirprojet/', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

The link have to use the Projet.nom_lien field in my database and redirect to the the project page.

Could someone help me please, I'm stuck and can't make it works.

Answer (score 0):

you want to store the link in the database

define in models.py a class Project

class Project(models.Model):

```
link_to_app = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

register it in the admin.py

```
in the admin panel enter the what you want Links

then you can access it like this in urls.py

from .models import Link

link = Projects.objects.get(pk=1)

my_link = link.link_to_app

then pass my_link to the url path


 urlpatterns += [
     path(my_link, views.index, name='index')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was focused in the template URL tag. But, I had just to put href="/voirprojet". 

With this href, clicking to the link in all my pages to see project details "/projectname", bring me to /projectname/voirprojet". And /projectname/voirprojet is define in all my APP urls file.